# Using Button from React Native and Native Base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using Native base library in React Native. 
In native base, there is component called Button and also there Component Button from 'react-native'.

If i want to use both Button components simultaneously, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/import)

```
import { Button } from 'react-native'
import { Button as ButtonBase } from 'native-base';
```

and

```
<Button /> {# React Native Button #}
<ButtonBase /> {# Native Base Button #}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use use ALIAS by adding word `as` between the default name and the new name you want example:

```
import {View as V} form react-native;
```

and in your `render()` function you can call it like the

```
<V>...</V>
```

so for your question you can do this you can do this

```
import {Button as ButtonMain} from react-native;
import {Button as ButtonRB} from react-native;
```

and you can call them in your `render()` function like this:

```
<ButtonMain />
<ButtonRB />
```